# How to access a text file from a java EXPORTED project eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I have a small program where it reads data from a text file. I am using Eclipse Java SE 1.6. The program is reading a file and displaying the results on a JLabel.

I am using **private Scanner x;** to go read my text file. Here is the function itself below:

```
public void readYearSetting()
{
    try {
        x = new Scanner(new File("yearSetting"));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Could not find file");
    }
    while(x.hasNext()) {
        String year = x.next();
        yearSetting = Integer.parseInt(year);
        displayingInsightsYearLabel.setText("Displaying " + year);
    }

}
```

I made a text file named **yearSetting**. The file itself does not have the extension of .txt which doesn't matter as it still opens it. I am working on a Macbook and have download Eclipse for my mac. (In case that helps).

The file is located within the main root folder. Which is no problem at all as it reads the files. When I click on the button "Run" from inside Eclipse, it runs smooth and great. So it works.

However, Now that i'm finished with the program, I would like to export it to be a standalone program the user can install and have. In order to do so, I know I must export as a JAR file. I have followed the steps on how to achieve that and I export it. But, it won't play the program. It crashes. Also calls a Null Pointer Exception error. And where I call for the method of **readYearSetting**, I comment it out to test it and then I export it as a JAR file and it works! So apparently it's not reading the files. I don't know why and how, if when I run it through eclipse it works fine.

I have looked and looked and no luck in finding an answer. I have moved the file to any where in the project you can think of, messed with the code and googled it but still no luck. So my question is, How would I get the program to read the file after the program is exported from eclipse as a JAR file. Am I missing something? Am I not suppose to use bufferedReader? Why is it not detecting the file? What's the correct way of reading a text file even after exporting your project as a JAR?

Comment: You can add exception stacktrace. Probably, the program is not able to locate the file and x is being set to null and x is being dereferenced in x.hasNext(), which throws a nullpointerexception.

Comment: It works when i run it through eclipse though, it reads the file and outputs it fine, however, when I export it as a JAR and try to run it, it fails. I try right clicking on the text files and selecting the option "Add to build path" but no luck. It gives me a ton of error messages in the Error log. The error log displays "Invalid ZIP archive" when i select "Add to build path" when i right click on the text file.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you pass only file name as `yearSetting` Change the file Name like and then try `yearSetting.txt`. and Check Full path of file Using Print Statement .
Demo Code to Read File Using Scanner :

```
 File file = new File("yearSetting.txt");
 try {
 Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
 while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
  String line = scanner.nextLine();
  System.out.println(line);
  }
  scanner.close();
  } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }`:
```

**Happy to Help**

Comment: I did what you typed, it didn't work, it works in eclipse, just like my code. But when I export it as a JAR file and try to open that one, it doesn't work. It doesn't load the text / read the file / find the file. I have tried over 5 hours now, make a project where you display a label, but the text you will display will come from a text file. It works with your code and my code, but try exporting it as a JAR file, and it doesn't work there. I'm getting to a point where I will just tell the user to download eclipse to use my program, which is very un-professional.

Comment: It's pretty weird though, I have images imported and being displayed and those actually do appear in the JAR executable, but not the text files. So i tried moving the text files into the images folder to have them linked and just modified the code to

     File file = new File("/iCustomClients/images/yearSetting.txt");

And it doesn't work. Same results.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, the text files are not like the images that are export along with the project. The Text files must be within the same place where the Java JAR file is exported to in order to read them. The text files will not be compiled inside the JAR file but rather physically outside where the .exe or JAR file program is located.